# single regex and group matching (named groups) to determine what criteria have been met in dart

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

```
final matches =
          RegExp(r'(?<case>.*(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]))(?<special>.*(?=.*[!#\$%&*@])|(?=.*[0-9]))(?<eightChar>.{8,})')
              .allMatches('passwordA4');
      final params = <String, String>{};
    
      for (final regMatch in matches) {
        if (regMatch != null) {
          for (final name in regMatch.groupNames) {
            params[name] = regMatch.namedGroup(name);
          }
          print(params);
        }
      }
```

If the string matches with "atleast eight charaacters" it will return named group **eightChar**. '
If the string matches with "An upper and lower case letter" it will return named group **Case**.
If the string matches with "At least one number or one of the following ! # $ % & * @ " it will return named group **Special**.

Can any one suggest me how to do this. My regular expression is not working properly

Comment: You are totally misled by how regex works. Use the suggested approach below.

Answer (score 0):

This code maybe be of help for you:

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  final asserts = {
    'uppercase': r'[A-Z]+',
    'lowercase': r'[a-z]+',
    'minimum length': r'.{8,}',
    'special char': r'[!#$%&*@]+'
  };
  final target = 'passwordA4';
  
  print('The word "$target" meets with');
  asserts.forEach((key, value) { 
    var header = '...$key';
    var spacer = ' '*(18 - header.length);
    print('$header$spacer: ${RegExp(value).hasMatch(target)}');
  });
}
```

Result:

```
The word "passwordA4" meets with
...uppercase      : true
...lowercase      : true
...minimum length : true
...special char   : false
```